# how to get a datatable to display it's data in a textbox

Tags: sql, datatable, textbox

everyone,

i am trying to get a textbox to display the result of a "AVG" select command to my sql server.

```
 Dim queryString As String = "select avg(pumpnum) from petrol_table"

        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString)

            Dim table As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(table)

            Dim row As DataRow = table.Rows(0)
            TextBox5.Text = row("pumpnum").ToString
```

if i put the column name in , i get an error that say that the column name does not exist.
if i leave out the column name, all i get in the textbox is "system.data.datarow."

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

while searching the net for an answer, i found this....

```
TextBox5.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(0)
```

works like a charm. :-)